# how to set map kit span and region that relate to the 2 coordinate distance?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am a beginner, I have 2 coordinates variable that can change dynamically based on the user position when they did a check in and check out in my app.

after I get the those 2 coordinates, I will add annotation to the map kit using this function.

```
func addMapAnnotation(coordinate: Coordinate, color: UIColor) {
        let span : MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0005, 0.0005)
        let location : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)
        let region : MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MyPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.pinTintColor = color
        mapKitView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

because I set the span and the region, and the 2 coordinates are dynamic ( i.e the distance between those 2 coordinates can be 1 km, or it can be 5 km, 10 km and so on), so there will be a chance that one of the annotation is not showed directly when the view controller appear for the first time, I have to zoom out first to see the second annotation.

what I want is, I want  to set Map Kit span and region dynamically based on the distance of 2 coordinates, so the user doesn't  have to zoom out to see both of the annotations

could you please help me share the code ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sh_Khan's answer is great, although a bit outdated. Here's an extension updated for Swift 5

```
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    init(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], spanMultiplier: CLLocationDistance = 1.8) {
        var topLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -90, longitude: 180)
        var bottomRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 90, longitude: -180)

        for coordinate in coordinates {
            topLeftCoord.longitude = min(topLeftCoord.longitude, coordinate.longitude)
            topLeftCoord.latitude = max(topLeftCoord.latitude, coordinate.latitude)

            bottomRightCoord.longitude = max(bottomRightCoord.longitude, coordinate.longitude)
            bottomRightCoord.latitude = min(bottomRightCoord.latitude, coordinate.latitude)
        }

        let cent = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5, longitude: topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: abs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * spanMultiplier, longitudeDelta: abs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * spanMultiplier)

        self.init(center: cent, span: span)
    }
}
```

Modify the `spanMultiplier` as you wish

Answer (score 1):

Call this function to zoom out and show all annotations

```
func zoomToFitMapAnnotations(aMapView:MKMapView)
{
    if(aMapView.annotations.count == 0)
    {
          return
    }


    var topLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: -90, longitude: 180)


    var bottomRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 90, longitude: -180)


    for i in 0..<myMapView.annotations.count
    {
        let annotation = myMapView.annotations[i]

        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
    }


    let resd = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5, longitude: topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpan.init(latitudeDelta: fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.3, longitudeDelta: fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.3)

    var region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: resd, span: span);



    region = aMapView.regionThatFits(region)

    aMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


}
```